# How do I pass a variable through a nested ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress-rest-api

I am doing an initial ajax call to get the post title from the WordPress Rest API, but I also need to get another value (siteServer) from another ajax call, but when I try to pass this I get 'undefined'. I assume this is due to an asynchronous issue, but not sure how to pass it up. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my jQuery code, but I am open to vanilla solutions as well.

```
function getPosts(object, query) {
  jQuery.ajax({ 
    type: 'GET', 
    url: query,  
  })
  .then( function (data, status, request) {
      jQuery.each(data, function(i, post) {
        let siteTitle = post['title']['rendered'];
        let siteServer = '12';
        jQuery(object).append(`
          <div class="get-post-item">
            <div class="site-title"><span>`+ siteTitle +`</span></div>
            <div class="site-server"><span>`+ getServerName(siteServer) +`</span></div>
          </div>
        `);
      });
    }
  })
}


function getServerName(id) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: '/wp-json/wp/v2/servers/' + id
  })
  .then(function (data, status, request) {
    let serverName = data['title']['rendered'];
    return serverName;
  })
}
```

Since I am only able to get the ID from the initial ajax call (simplified in the above code as a static string var "let siteServer = '12'") I need to do the second/nested ajax call to get the Title and pass to the .append in the first call.